# How to set up redux in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux

My code:

```
function App({ isAuthenticated }) {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [token, setToken] = useState()
    const [appLoaded, setAppLoading] = useState(false)
    const routes = buysellRoutes(isAuthenticated, token);

     const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
         Inter_900Black,
     })
   

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
        <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
            { appLoaded && fontsLoaded ? routes : <PreLoadScreen />}
        </ApplicationProvider>
        </Provider>
    )
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.**

Comment: Use useSelector and useDispatch instead connect HOC. try to use this approach - codesandbox.io/s/oj7px08qy9?file=/store.js

Comment: I've updated my post to using the dispatch action in your case, give me feedback. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your implementation. I'll try to explain them step by step:

First, you need a `store.js` file to create your store outside of your `App.js`. for more information take a look at its [documentation](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore).

Second, the `App` component is considered as the root component in the react structure so avoid passing the props to the root component which is clearly wrong.

Third, you need to pass the `store` through of `<Provider store={store} >` and consume the store (get store's data as a state) in the components or pages with `useSelector` method, and no more need to `mapStateTopProps`.

**Note:** you must define and pass the store to the Top-level component and use it inside of the **children**.

**Note:** to check the `isAuthenticated` property, separate your `ApplicationProvider`  and create a component for it.

```
function SomeComponent() {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.auth.isAuthenticated)
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [token, setToken] = useState()
  const [appLoaded, setAppLoading] = useState(false)
  const routes = buysellRoutes(isAuthenticated, token);
  
  return(
    <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
      { appLoaded && fontsLoaded ? routes : <PreLoadScreen />}
    </ApplicationProvider>
  )
}
```

##### Optionally:

You may need to dispatch some actions in your component, with react hooks it's easy with `useSelector` and `useDispatch` without `mapStateToProps` or `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
function SomeExampleComponent () {
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
 const handleToggle = () => {
   // ...
   dispatch({type: "TOGGLE", payload: undefiend})
   // or you can dispatch some actions that you defined before:
   dispatch(onToggleAction())
 }  

 return (
   <div onClick={handleToggle}>
     // ... 
   </div>
 )}
```

Comment: Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Comment: const handleToggle = () => {
        dispatch(login({code: value, phone: phone}))
    }

Comment: can you create a `codesandbox` from your implementation to check it? @ТахирМухаметов

Answer (score 2):

Here the main issue is you cannot connect the main component without a provider, so create one HOC and provide the store to the whole app and then after you can connect.

Another way is, you can use **context** in inner components so you don't need to connect the component just provide the store to the main HOC.

You can refer to this project for the initial react native app setup
[react native starter project with redux](https://github.com/sonalmaniya/react-native-boots)